# Permission denied when opening a file on desktop with fopen

Tags: c++, win-universal-app

I'm trying the following code, but it returns EACCESS (permission denied). I really don't know why. I even tried to run VS in Administrator mode, without success. It always works well.. maybe because it is windows universal app?

```
auto err = _wfopen_s(&f, L"C:/Users/Lukas/Desktop/Audio.mp3", L"rb");
if (err > 0)
    return;

fseek(f, SEEK_END, 0);
unsigned int size = ftell(f);
fseek(f, SEEK_SET, 0);

char *data = new char[size];
fread(data, 1, size, f);

fclose(f);
```

Comment: Are you certain the file is not opened elsewhere (either by your own program where you havn't called fclose() or some other program ?)

Comment: @nos Yes I am. I restarted the computer and this code is called immediately after initializing TCP

Comment: I've tried different files as well. The same error occurs

Comment: I'm not sure about universal apps, but for a traditional Windows program, `GetLastError()` should return the underlying Windows OS error that's causing the C RTL `EACCESS` error. Does it give you any more info?

Comment: @JoshKelley GetLastError outputs 5.. not sure how to check what it is.

Comment: You can use the error lookup tool in visual studio. But in this case 5 will simply yield "access is denied". You might want to check the security settings on that file to make sure you have read access.

Comment: @Ferruccio I've tried with different files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is expected for a Universal Windows app.  Windows Runtime apps run in a sandbox and do not have access to arbitrary parts of the file system. They can directly access (e.g. via fopen, etc.)only their appx package (read only) and app data (read write) directories. All other locations are available only with user permission through the StorageFile and StorageFolder broker objects.

To access your MP3 on the desktop you'll need to have the user select it with a file picker (or equivalent) to get a StorageFile with appropriate permissions, which can then be cached for later use with the AccessCache classes. Alternatively, put the MP3 in the music library and the app can declare the music library capability and get a StorageFile via the KnownFolders.MusicLibrary folder.

I go into more detail in my blog entry at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2012/12/05/stray-from-the-path-stick-to-the-storagefile.aspx